# Comparing quality of automatically labeled data

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, labeling, automatic-algorithms

I have two algorithms for automatically labeling data for a computer vision task. The dataset is large, and it's not feasible to inspect visually.
Can I determine which labeling is higher quality based on the ability to train/validate on the same samples?
If I suspect that one of the methods is systematically wrong, then the model may learn this pattern and the validation error will not indicate the quality of the data.

Comment: You can do visual inspection on a random sample of cases where the two methods give different labels.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but I'm not sure I can decide which one is better in terms of consistency that may be learned by my model.